# How can I setup a standard user to run a scheduled task on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, scheduled-task, user-permissions

How can I setup a standard user to run a scheduled task on Windows Server 2012?

I tried to simply add a user, but the batch fails.

I tried to add "Log on as batch job right" via gpo, but it fails again.

What do I have to grant?

Maybe it fails because it should be a domain admin to log in a server machine?

Comment: What type of task is it? Does the task required specific permissions? Did you confirm that the GPO actually applied?

Comment: Yes, it is applied. Should it be enought? Task runs a php script, but what I saw in the history log seems not be connected to what it does but the logon authoriazion of the user.